# Random Shuffle Game

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, random, shuffle

I'm relatively new to C#, and am currently working on a shuffle game. The idea is that the numbers are shuffled when the user presses 'new game', and the user then has to get the tiles in descending order by swapping the empty block with any adjacent number.

I'm using the Form Application which has 25 buttons. The 25th button is left blank. I need to be able to have each text on the button changed to a random number when a button 'shuffle' is pressed.

The swapping of numbers works, but I can't manage to create a random shuffle without having either duplicate numbers or having a '0'.

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. 
Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? 
Show your effort first so people might show theirs. 
Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start..